# Reading HMC5883L hex values in 2's compliment C code

Tags: arduino-nano, i2c, c, gyroscope

I want to develop my C code for HMC5883L.

I have 2 questions for my current code development.

My first question is:
But what I found in the datasheet is that the values are in the 2's compliment, so I don't know how to deal with them?! Do I have to take the values as they are in the data registers and convert them to decimal values and that's it? Or I have to convert them from 2's compliment to the original hex values?

This is a quote from the datasheet:

> Send 0x3D 0x06 (Read all 6 bytes. If gain is changed then this data set is using previous gain)
>   Convert three 16-bit 2’s compliment hex values to decimal values and assign to X, Z, Y, respectively.

My second question:
How o read the data registers? What is the procedure?
I saw in the datasheet the following method but I didn't understand it.

> Loop
>   Send 0x3D 0x06 (Read all 6 bytes. If gain is changed then this data set is using previous gain)
>   Convert three 16-bit 2’s compliment hex values to decimal values and assign to X, Z, Y, respectively.
>   Send 0x3C 0x03 (point to first data register 03)
>   Wait about 67 ms (if 15 Hz rate) or monitor status register or DRDY hardware interrupt pin
>   End_loop

So, I didn't understand that I send read command then I send write command, so how HMC5883L would return the value to me?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2's complement is the normal signed values in any modern system, including Arduino.

Just place the bytes into a signed variable of the right size in the right positions and there is your value.

In I2C, to read a register, you typically have to make two transactions. The first is a write to set the register number you want to access, the you follow that with a read transaction to get the data.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60167/discussion-on-answer-by-majenko-reading-hmc5883l-hex-values-in-2s-compliment-c).

Comment: Any comments that amplify on the answer should be merged into the answer. Anyone with sufficient reputation can do that.